# history of programming in ... DOS times (not console)

Tags: ide

first of all - thank you in advance for all answers.
Second - I'm not asking about writing console programs working on modern systems (like Ubuntu 11.10 or Windows 7) nor batch files.
Third - I'm not going to become DOS 6.22 nor Windows 3.1 programs developer. Maybe I will write small program only for educational purpose.

I am wondering how programmers works on early (I refer to 70's, 80's and begining of 90's) days of computer. On wikipedia there's many information about, let's caled it "ancient times", but there's not enough about "middle ages" (I'm referring to 70-90's) in programming definition. Although in DOS times programs higly depends on used machines (because they directly call hardware IRQ), I can't believe that there wasn't something like today Integrated Development Environment and that some of them were written in high level programming language. Is it possible that [Prehistoric 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistorik_2) has been written in Assembly? I don't think so, but I assume that early versions of BASIC can't receive such possibility.

Could you recommend any good article or source of information? I'm interested both MS (DOS, Windows 16-bit) and Unix platforms.

Comment: Have you considered asking this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ? This is *off-topic* for stackoverflow.

Comment: The Wikipedia article about Turbo Pascal captures the spirit if the early 1980s. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Pascal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [Borland Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) and [Borland C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_C%2B%2B), commonly used in the early 90s.

If memory serves, [Commander Keen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander_Keen) was built using Borland tools. It's probable that other same-era [Apogee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apogee_Software)/[id](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id_Software) games (like the original 2D [Duke Nukem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duke_Nukem_%28character%29)) were built under Borland as well.

Later on (early-to-mid 90s), id Software started using [Watcom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcom_C_compiler) and the [DOS/4GW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS/4G) DOS extender to build games like the original [DOOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doom_%28video_game%29).

Answer (score 2):

I was working in that period on Windows 16-bit and DOS (also DEC VAX and Alpha).
Mostly I used Turbo Pascal and Delphi 1 both of which provided IDE's. This was in the early 90's